# How do I format the output of this Python program?

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to get these sets of values to line up from left to right (see below). 
How could I do this?

```
def main():
    for temp in range(-20, 70, 10):
        for windspeed in range(5, 55, 5):
            print int(35.74 + (0.6215*(temp)) - (35.75* windspeed**0.16) + (0.4275*(temp)) * (windspeed**0.16)),
        print
main()
```

Right now the output is vertical

```
-34
-40
-45
-48
-50
-53
-54
-56
-58
-59

-22
-28
-32
-35
-37
-39
-41
-42
-44
-45
```

I want it like this:

```
-34 -22
-40 -28
-45 -32
-48 -35
-50 -37
-53 -39
-54 -41
-56 -42
-58 -44
-59 -45
```

Comment: I know, it didn't format on here like it should have...I'll try and repost the output.

Comment: @user Just as a tip, the trick with output is to format it as if it was code, then it comes out verbatim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to transpose your output which you can do by reversing the order of the loops. As a special bonus I have formatted the output so that it appears in nice neat colums!

```
for windspeed in range(5, 55, 5):
    for temp in range(-20, 70, 10):
        print "%3d" % int(35.74 + (0.6215*(temp)) - (35.75* windspeed**0.16) + (0.4275*(temp)) * (windspeed**0.16)),
    print
```

Output:

```
-34 -22 -10   1  12  24  36  48  59
-40 -28 -15  -3   8  21  33  46  58
-45 -32 -19  -6   6  19  31  44  57
-48 -35 -21  -8   4  17  30  43  56
-50 -37 -24 -10   2  16  29  42  56
-53 -39 -25 -12   1  14  28  42  55
-54 -41 -27 -13   0  13  27  41  55
-56 -42 -28 -14   0  13  26  40  54
-58 -44 -29 -15  -1  12  26  40  54
-59 -45 -31 -16  -2  11  25  39  54
```

I am guessing, to a degree, that this is what you want because what you state to be the output of the program in your question is not what that program actually outputs. I hope I've understood correctly.

Comment: Oh wow, that's it!!! Programming makes me feel really dumb. :D Thanks for the reply back though, I do appreciate it. o/

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
   output = ""
   for temp in range(-20, 70, 10):
      for windspeed in range(5, 55, 5):
         output = output + str(int(35.74 + (0.6215*(temp)) - (35.75* windspeed**0.16) + (0.4275*(temp)) * (windspeed**0.16)))
   print output

main()
```